# Lithium 72V (2x 36V series) charging with double 36V charger for ebike project

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, electric-vehicle

[image: Voltage is wrong but here basic wiring diagram for parallel to series changeover switch]

Edit1: Voltage is wrong but here is a basic wiring diagram for a parallel to series changeover switch I found on internet closest to what I want.

I want to 2 36v battery packs in series. I know that to protect the BMS I need to put some diode in parellel with each pack.

How can I switch the battery from series to parallel but isolated from each other? I want to plug in both chargers at the same time.

Do you know how can I charge both batteries with same (or higher current charger) 36V-2A charger with the problem of parelleling some batteries that may or may not be out of balance at the time of the connection.

I saw some wiring diagrams with changeover switch but it's not an isolated  parallel.

PS: It's not an actual ebike but the same power system  is used in my electric scooter.

I plan on a 2000 watt 60V brushless motor similar to my 1020 but brushless 
and a controller that can handle 36-72V 3000watt (45A.)

I will seriously limit the power given to the motor because that's a lot obviously.

Edit3: Some aditonal specifications:

The lithium battery packs I've got my eye on are 40ACDR 60 peak 36V cell themself at 10A  and its 6P10S should be able to handle 60A CDR so I'm safe.

For giggles, here's the scooter in question. I already know I am going to put the 2  20Ah36V battery  (battery holder will go behind the seat there space for it.)

[image: scooter]

Comment: Your question is technically very hard to follow. Can you extract the core "must haves" and make a clear specific question. | You can connect seperate chargers tyo two hard connected series batteries IF the charger outputs float. If the charger inputs do NOT float then the batteries need to be isolated from each other during charge. a simple SPST switch does that  .| If you have 2 x (6S20) batteries in series during operation and parallel during charge then a DPDT switch is needed.

Comment: i will try making clear 
i want a way to charge both lithium battery with 2 charger 36v when the battery are in series

but will it cause problem if i jsut take the charge  wire and put it to 2 charger port? .

I have no idea of the spec of the charger since i didn't get delivered the first battery (lead acid are dying every month now).
Each battery pack are in 10S and 6P for 60A max BMS at 40A.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please confirm. You have

- 2 x 10S6P LiIon batteries.
- 2 x 42V MAX chargers designed for use as 6S LiIon chargers.

Note - these CANNOT be "36V chargers". 
10S = 36V AVERAGE but 4.2V x 10 = 42V charged.

You also say 44 Volt.
44V = 4.4V/cell is damagingly high for most LiIon.

Chargers MUST suit battery. Can you provide brand and model for chargers and batteries?

What is the manufacturers max charge rate?
What is the battery Ah rating per cell.

IF the cells are 18650s and arranged 6P then max current is probably either
about 6 x 3A = 18A at 1C or
6 x 1.5A = 9A at 0.5C.
This depends on the battery specification.

Charger Imax can be checked by measuring Ichg with a discharged battery.
Charger Vmax can be checked by measuring battery voltage at end of charge.
Vmax MUST NOT be above 42V for 6S pack unless manufacturer very specifically says so.

**_____________________________________________________________**

Diagrammatic only.
SW2 & SW3 may be combined as a DPST switch or relay.
ALL switches can be combined as a DT3P switch or relay BUT SW1 NC contact MUST open first when operating and close last when de-operating.
**MUST**

IF chargers are floating (-ve output not grounded) then they may be directly connected to batteries with no switching.  This may be advantageous enough to justify use of an isolating transformer for one charger

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGybH3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Charger come with the battery on purchase diagram shown is wrong voltage.
Panasonic NCR-18650BD 10 cell in Series 6 in Parallel confirmed by the seller directly factory
i purchase only 1 battery so before i screw myself i ask but will buy a second if everything is clear
Edit1: i know i say voltage wrong but they are know to replace 36V lead acid hence why we call them 36v  sorry for missleading

Comment: there edited the image somewhat to fit  somewhat the spec

Comment: @buder5 Please answer questions in my answer. | NCR18540 is 3200 mAh, 4.2V max, Chg std = 1.625A (= C/2) . They do not appear to be high current rated - I have a brief data sheet here. Link? | 6s batteries are 42V **MAX**. || QUESTION: IAre your chargers 6S chargers? . Question: In scooter are batteries arranged in series for 20S or parallel for 12P?

Comment: 2 Lithium Ion pack each 60cell 10Series 6Parrellel  i want to put them in series without dismantling the whole pack
here battery spec 
Model: NCR18650BD
Size: 18650
Style: Flat Top
Chemistry: NCR
Nominal Capacity: 3180mAh
Continuous Discharge Rating: 10A
Nominal Voltage: 3.6v

Comment: charger come with battery  At Purchase

Comment: NCR18650BD is the cell used in the pack

Answer (score -2):

Try to put rectifier diode in between two batteries to connect them to series so that you can connect the charger to either side coz diode control polarity

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please try to add more reasoning and explanation to your answer. In general answers consisting of single sentences usually don't fit the needs of this Q&A-site. Also try to make clear how you address the problem of the OP. Schematics are always a good idea.